# Android 3.0 emulator only showing a fraction of the app when loaded

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-layout

So I've searched for an answer but found nothing. Basically, whenever I run a simple little menu app for android tablets using the eclipse android emulator 3.0, only about 1/6th of the app is shown (the top center piece, if the tablet is held landscape.) I've done tutorials using the 2.2 emulator and they work just fine, but whenever I launch the 3.0, the app (and only the app - the android home runs fine) just doesn't appear. When I look at it in the main.xml layout folder, the graphical layout shows it exactly the way I want it to appear.
Is this a problem with the emulator? This can't be a common problem, otherwise I'm sure I would have found a solution by now, but there must be some switch or something that I'm not seeing that's making the app appear as if it were running on a phone and not a tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a low resolution set for your 3.0 AVD? If you run the [AVD Manager](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds.html), what resolution does it show?